# PC boot, hibernation and sleep problems

Tags: windows-10, boot, sleep, hibernate, desktop-computer

After I click the button to turn the PC on, it starts and shuts down three times before booting and it happens every single time. Also every time I send it to hibernation mode or to sleep after few seconds it turns back on by itself.
What should I do?
I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Is everything running okay when the PC finally boots?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine. I have tried reinstalling system, but it didn't help.

Comment: I would suggest that your power supply is failing.  It's not generating enough on the first boot but subsequent boots works.  It is also sending false wake up signals to a hibernating motherboard.  If it's not, it's the motherboard but a new psu is easier and cheaper to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analyze power/sleep problems, start Command Prompt (cmd) that is Run as Administrator and enter the command :

```
powercfg -energy
```

An article that explains the report is
[Use PowerCfg in Windows 7 to Evaluate Power Efficiency](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/).
If you wish us to have a look - please post the report.

Some other advice :

- [Turn Off Fast Startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)
- [Disable Hybrid Sleep](https://techjourney.net/turn-off-and-disable-hybrid-sleep-in-windows-10-8-1-8-7-vista/)
- [Run SFC command](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) to verify system integrity

Let us know whether this helped.

Comment: Thanks for response!
powercfg -energy shows there are 15 Errors, 15 Warnings and 22 Informational. I am going to try to solve them, if I find something difficult to fix, I'll fell free to ask you for help :).

Comment: That's what we all are here for.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly could be related to power supply or green energy programming.

But also, be sure to download [Microsoft Sysinternals Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) or [WinPatrol](http://www.winpatrol.com/download.html) and see if something is stuck in an installation or uninstallation loop.

Start by looking at the "runonce" section.

It should always be empty unless something has been scheduled to run at the next boot.